# RegEx to select everything inside a div

Tags: javascript

I googled my fingers wound and all the solutions I found won't work.
Im trying to replace a div like the following:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("first");

// Get modal content and replace the footer with content
var oldContent = modal.innerHTML;

// Set modal content
modal.innerHTML = oldContent.replace(/<div class="two">(.*?)<\/div>/, '<div class="two">' + 'Content' + '</div>');
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="first">
  <div class="one">This is the first one</div>
  <div class="two">Second one</div>
</div>
```

Im trying to replace everything in the second div.
Currently my code is like this and I tried so select everything with regex, but it just wont work.

Comment: Why are you using a reg exp? Makes no sense to do that.

Comment: Why not `document.getElementByClassName("two").innerHTML = "Content"`

Comment: Do not use regular expression for parsing html/xml. This is why libraries like jQuery exist!

Comment: Don't use RegEx for this, but the reason your code doesn't work is because you just weren't running the HTML against the JS (at least on your post). When I created a single post, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for what you need:

```
document.querySelector('div.two').innerHTML = 'Content';
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes no sense to change content with a regular expression when you can access the element. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on why it is bad idea.

Just reference the element from the modal and set the innerHTML or textContent with the value you want.

```
modal.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].innerHTML = "new text";
```

or

```
modal.querySelector(".two").innerHTML = "new text";
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion, the OP code does work though... See my comment on the question